# Nvidia OpenCL Build log gets cut off at 4KB

Tags: linux, opencl, nvidia

I have 24 kernels in a single OpenCL file and am interested to find out how many registers they use on my Nvidia Card. The kernels are built by OpenCL using the switch *"-cl-nv-verbose"* and the Build log is written to file. The size of the log is queried and memory is allocated for it on the stack. The log gets fetched and is written to a file on the disk. All OpenCL commands are checked and complete successfully. The problem is that the size of the build log seems to be limited to 4097 bytes.

```
// Get build log
size_t build_log_size;
clGetProgramBuildInfo(program, device, CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG, 0, NULL, &build_log_size);

std::cout << "Size of Build log: " << build_log_size << std::endl;
char *build_log = (char*) alloca(build_log_size);
clGetProgramBuildInfo(program, device, CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG, build_log_size, build_log, NULL);

// Write out build log
std::string build_log_string(build_log);
std::ofstream build_log_file(STR_BUILD_LOG);
if (!build_log_file.is_open()) {
    std::cerr << "Could not open " << STR_BUILD_LOG << std::endl;
} else {
    build_log_file << build_log_string;
}

build_log_file.close();
```

This is what I get in my build log on the last lines:

```
Compiling entry function 'kernel12' for 'sm_30'
ptxas info    : Function properties for kernel12
0 bytes stack frame, 0 bytes spill stores, 0 bytes spill loads
ptxas info    : Used 18 registers, 336 bytes cmem[0], 4 bytes cmem[2], 152 bytes cmem[3]
ptxas info    : Compiling entry function 'kernel13' for 'sm_30'
ptxas info    : Function properties for kernel13
0 bytes st
```

That's it, it just cuts off there at around the 13th kernel out of the total 24 one byte after the 4KB marker. I have tried giving the build log over 200KB of heap memory as well but still only got the limited log back. I am using Ubuntu 12.10 and a Geforce 680GTX OpenCL driver version 304.88 according to clinfo. What is preventing me from getting the rest of the log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I split the input file into smaller source files and compiled each separately. That bypassed the issue.